# Getting every related entity in Entity Framework 6.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

```
public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}

public class Operation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `Service` entity which is used in other entities. I want to get all entities that use `Service`.

What I mean is get a list of entities that use `Service` like this:

```
public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
```

Is this possible in Entity Framework?

Comment: Why not adding other entities as navigation property to `Service`?

Comment: Because it doesn't matter . I don't want the data  . I just want to get all entities that use Service . list of ' dbset ' that use service

Comment: Well, the question is not about entity framework at all now. What you seek is reflection.

Comment: @ilkerkaran May not be true, see my comment below.

Comment: @GertArnold, Actually he can access Context Properties and enumerate through their types etc. Entity Framework is just an example of detail when OP asks the class relations and accessing Types.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via reflection. Approximate code, where `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` can be replaced with appropriate Assembly/Assemblies:

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.GetProperties().Any(y => y.PropertyType == typeof(Service)))
            .ToList();

(instance.GetType().GetProperties().Where(y => y.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet<Service>))
.First().GetValue(instance) as DbSet<Service>).Add(newItem);
```

Comment: tanks for answer. I think is correct . but how to convert types list to dbset ? i need to use types for add or remove .

Comment: You can get `DbSet<Service>` property from some instance, cast it to target type and call appropriate method, all of it also via reflection. Look at updated answer.

Comment: tank you for replay i want convert instance to related list .  foreach (var e in types)
           {

               var entity = e as DbSet<e.name>; // entity is store or product or operation , ...  is not Service
           }

Comment: Note that this finds all properties of type `Service`, also when they are in non-entity types and unmapped properties. This could be a problem and if so, it will be necessary to use EF's metadata to find the correct properties.

Comment: @GertArnold, at this case we can add additional hint - for example, place all interested in classes at specific namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Add navigational ServiceId and use that.
You are probably showing a simplification of your code but I would do something like this:

```
public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectUsingService> MyServiceUsers {get; set;
}

public ObjectUsingService
{
    public int? ServiceId {get; set;}
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}

public class Store : ObjectUsingService
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

//...
```

And then query EF from the other end:

```
_context.Services.Include(s => s.MyServiceUsers).Where(s => s.MyServiceUsers.Any())
```

One level of inheritance is doable in EF but be wary, it might get messy if you overuse it. The problem with not having them connected this way is not too bad, you only have to ask for each entity separatly.